# In turbulence what to we mean that an eddy has a wavenumber k?

Tags: energy, plasma-physics, turbulence

In turbulence what to we mean that an eddy has a wavenumber k?

Comment: Different wavenumbers correspond to different length scale fluctuations.  One of the basic ideas of turbulence is that energy cascades from large to small scales, thus, a spectrum of different wavenumbers play a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In turbulence what to we mean that an eddy has a wavenumber k?

Not all eddies are created equal, if you will.  That is, they need not be all the same spatial size.  Different wavenumbers correspond to different length scale fluctuations.  One of the basic ideas of [turbulence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) is that energy cascades from large to small scales, thus, a spectrum of different wavenumbers play a role.

A specific type of eddy is generated by the [Kelvin-Helmholtz instability](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kelvin-Helmholtz_Instability_and_Roll-up), which can be described using the typical wave phase parameters, i.e., $\phi = \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega \ t$, where $\phi$ is the phase, $\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector, $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector position of the phase, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, and $t$ is the time.  If the system is turbulent, an initial, large eddy can generate within itself smaller and smaller eddies, each with different $k$ and $\omega$.